# Zend with Sub Forms returning subform as an array within array form data, how to return a single array?

Tags: zend-framework

How to return as a dingle array?

Form is added as follows:

```
   $this->addSubForms(array(new Form_ThisForm(),new Form_ThatForm()));
    $this->addElements(array($sort, $order, $submit, $clear));
```

Developer Tools Dump:

```
    id:
    u_before:
    u_after:
    status:none
    last:
    first:
    cell:
    1[name]:
    1[s_before]:2014-02-05
    1[s_after]:2013-07-01
    1[region]:1
    1[city]:
    1[division]:
    sort:entrydate
    order:asc
    submit:Search
```

var_dump():

```
array (size=11)
  'id' => string '' (length=0)
  'u_before' => string '' (length=0)
  'u_after' => string '' (length=0)
  'status' => string 'none' (length=4)
  'last' => string '' (length=0)
  'first' => string '' (length=0)
  'cell' => string '' (length=0)
  1 => 
    array (size=6)
      'name' => string '' (length=0)
      's_before' => string '2014-02-05' (length=10)
      's_after' => string '2013-07-01' (length=10)
      'region' => string '1' (length=1)
      'city' => string '' (length=0)
      'division' => string '' (length=0)
  'sort' => string 'entrydate' (length=9)
  'order' => string 'asc' (length=3)
  'submit' => string 'Search' (length=6)
```

Comment: What you want to ask???

Comment: Oh sorry, updated question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want your subforms to be nested in resulting values array, override subform's

```
protected $_isArray = false;
```

or call `$subForm->setIsArray(false);`